# Implement Google Analytics funnel for sign up with authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, authlogic

I have a rails application for which uses authlogic for sign up. I am trying to implement a google analytics funnel to find out how many people signed up. The way authlogic works is, when a user creates an account an email is sent to him with an activation link. When the users clicks on the activation link his sign up is completed. I was wondering if google analytics funnel would give me the correct stats as the user will have to leave the site in order to click his activation link.

Answer (score 1):

The way I went about this is,

1. Created a funnel for the user sign-up page(where the user enters his credentials and hits the create account button) and made the subsequent url unique.
2. Added an Event to the create account button click.
3. Created a goal for the activation url.